# Prove or disprove these statements.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

I have this statement and I need to prove or disprove it. Any help is appreciated.

(1) Is it possible for solution set of a system [A| $\vec{b}^.$] of three equations and three variables, and  $\vec{b}^.$ $\neq$  $\vec{0}^.$ to be a plane through the origin.

Comment: please write a better title for your question !

Answer (score 2):

For the first statement, if the point $(0,0,0)$ is in the solution set of $[A|b]$, then placing this point in the equations would solve it. What is the solution of any system of linear equations, when placing the origin as the solution?

For the second statement try using the dimension theorem. That is, take $V,W$ to be hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then $\dim V=\dim W=3$, now use the fact that

$dim(V+W)=\dim V+\dim W-\dim(V\cap W)$

and the fact that $\dim(V+W)\leq 4$. What can $\dim(V\cap W)$ be?

Comment: For the first statement the hypothesis states that the solution set cannot be the zero vector. 

For the second statement, is it fair for me to say that since the dimensions of V & W is 3 then the intersection of V & W must be a plane?

Comment: The intersection is not necessarily a plane, maybe V=W. In order to disprove the second statement, all you need to show is that the dimension of the intersection must be greater then 1.

Comment: Okay. And for the first statement? If the hypothesis states that the solution cannot be the zero vector, is it still possible for the solution set to be a plane through the origin?

Comment: If the solution set is a plane through the origin, then in particular the origin is in this set, which means the origin solves these equations.